# Call to viewWillLayoutSubviews infintely which results in screen freezing and memory warnings

Tags: ios, objective-c

In my code, I am getting infinite call to `viewWillLayoutSubviews` method. In `viewWillLayoutSubviews`, I am reloading the table which results in huge memory leak which results into screen freezing on my iPad 2.

```
- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews {
  [super viewWillLayoutSubviews];

  if ([APP_DELEGATE popOverIsOpened]) {

    [socalMedia dismissView];
    [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(exiBack) withObject:nil];
  }
  [self.pTableView reloadData];
  if (([[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation] ==
       UIDeviceOrientationPortrait) ||
      ([[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation] ==
       UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)) {
    _pView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 768, 1024)];
    webView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 64, 768, 1024 - 64);
  } else {

    _pView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 768)];
    webView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 64, 1024, 768 - 64);
  }

  CGRect frm = self.navigationController.view.frame;
  frm.origin.y = 0;
  self.navigationController.view.frame = frm;

}
```

At what instances, `viewWillLayoutSubviews` method called? Is it call automatically or when orientation changes or what?

Answer (score 0):

The viewWillLayoutSubviews method gets called when View resized (here you setting frm to self.navigationController.view.frame) and positioned by its parent.

Comment: If viewWillLayoutSubviews method called up when view resized, then why it gets into infinite calls on my code! Initially when view rendered, then there will be one call but not infinite.

Comment: try commenting this "CGRect frm = self.navigationController.view.frame;
  frm.origin.y = 0;
  self.navigationController.view.frame = frm;"

Answer (score 0):

You better do one thing take a bool and set it TRUE on button press and check it on layoutSubviews and operate whether it is true or false. You get it what i am trying to do.It will make sure that layoutSubView not called infinity and which will help the app not to freeze and no memory warnings.

Comment: Thanks Prabhjot for answering. Your solution may work, but I want to know the exact reason when this viewWillLayoutSubviews method called. What causes to layout subviews again and again.

Comment: hi @pkc456 The viewWillLayoutSubviews method is also called after the view is resized and positioned by its parent. So it will cause viewWillLayoutSubviews method to be called infinite times.

Comment: and also @pkc456 Given viewWillLayoutSubviews is called whenever the bounds change on the controller's view, there's no guarantee that it'll be invoked once only. It'll be called whenever rotation occurs